# sfdx force:source:push ignores Custom Labels

Tags: salesforcedx

I was able to pull Custom Labels from a scratch org using sfdx force:source:pull, but when I tried pushing the labels to a fresh scratch org, or new labels to an existing scratch org, the push fails on any code that references the labels.

If I comment out the code that references the labels, I can push the source, but the labels are not added to the scratch org.

Comment: The [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/44/CustomLabels/issues) is *currently* showing full support for Custom Labels in this scenario with the exception of one [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWY4QAO). That isn't to say there isn't an unknown bug here. What does `force:source:status` show in relation to the custom labels?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: the `<value>` tag was missing from one of the Custom label definitions, which prevented the CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml file from loading.  The error message was not helpful.

```
PROJECT PATH                                               ERROR
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
N/A                                                        Main markup cannot be empty. If you are trying to delete the Lightning definition bundle, directly delete the bundle instead.
N/A                                                        Required field is missing: value (31:13)
force-app\main\default\aura\PostContent\PostContent.cmp    Label Share_Count cannot be found in namespace c.
N/A                                                        We couldn't validate your component. Review it and try again. The following code has invalid references which caused safe validation failure. AuraDefinition [
                                                           id:null
                                                           deftype:null
                                                           format:null
                                                           source:
                                                           null] (0:0)
```